# How to create an increment of 0.01 value once you click a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="sum">0.01</div>
<div id="num"></div>
<button></button>
```

```
    i = 0;
$("button").click(function() {
      var sum = $("#sum").html();
      i += sum;
      $("#num").html(i.toFixed(2));
});
```

Every time you press the button, the value 0.01 should increase by +0.01. So if I press the button 5 times that should give the value 0.05.
but my code doesn't work, the error is:

> i.toFixed(2) is not a function

And when I remove `toFixed(2)`, it works but it increases by like this `0.01 0.01 0.01` into the div if I clicked 3 times.

Comment: `$("#sum").html()` returns a string. If you add strings, they are concatenated. Try `Number($("#sum").html())` to make it a number before you add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because `$("#sum").html()` is `string`

You need to parse it to `float`. Then increment it.

```js
i = 0;
$("button").click(function() {
      var sum = parseFloat($("#sum").html());
      i += sum;
      $("#num").html(i.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sum">0.01</div>
<div id="num"></div>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. bro! Your code works fine. I didn't know the (parseFloat) instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var i = 0.01;
var num = 0.01;
document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON")[0].onclick = () => {
  num += i;
  document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML=num
}
```

Comment: Thanks again. this also works but I've used your first answer above and has been verified.